# How to print no.of users logged into the linux server along with shell from /etc/passwd file in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am planning to print a number of users logged into the Linux server along with shell from /etc/passwd. below command is counting the users

```
awk -F: '$3>=1000 && $3<65534 {i+=1}; END {print i}' /etc/passwd

awk -F: '$3>=1000 && $3<65534 {i+=1}; END {print i, $7 }' /etc/passwd
1 /bin/bash


awk -F: '$3>=1000 && $3<65534 {i+=1}; END {print $1, i, $7}'  /etc/passwd

username 87 /bin/bash
```

That username prints last row username in the /etc/passwd file.  I am planning to print all the usernames along with the shell. can some try to help me

Comment: You seem to have everything in place to do what you are trying to do. What's not working? What *exactly* are you trying to output? Best would be to show the desired output vs. what you have got.

Comment: What do you mean by *"a number of users logged into the Linux server"*? Do you mean really logged in like the output of `who`, or simply the users who have Unix *accounts* on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have this:

```
awk -F: '$3>=1000 && $3<65534 {print $1,++i,$7}' /etc/passwd
```

The `END` block will be executed only if the last input line was finish processed. So your codes printed only the last line.

Btw, this is just some filtering on `/etc/passwd`, it is not currently logged in users.

Comment: Thank you for Response.  How can we print current logged in users along with shell.  even I have tried to print current logged in users using the following commands, like " w", "who",  "last" , finger, users. I did not see any  shell over there. May I know do you have any idea

Comment: using that it will not print what shell are we using root@ansibletestingserver:~# w
 09:25:44 up 1 day,  6:09,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
ubuntu   pts/0    ec2-54-243-132-8 09:24    1.00s  0.06s  0.00s sshd: ubuntu [priv]  like that it will print he I do not find any shell

Comment: @mahesh you can join w/who output and /etc/pwd file